# select in solr search is not working

Tags: solr

I have configured solr, such that, it can index records from postgres database. It's uploaded successfully. And if I pass query string as `*:*`, it produce a response of all rows in the table. But when i specify the search, the result is always 0.

My XML response when query string `*:*` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
   <int name="status">0</int> 
   <int name="QTime">0</int> 
   <lst name="params">
      <str name="q">*:*</str> 
   </lst>
 </lst>
 <result name="response" numFound="3" start="0">
 <doc>
<str name="names">sample1</str> 
<str name="sno">1</str> 
<str name="values">3</str> 
</doc>
 <doc>
<str name="names">sample2</str> 
<str name="sno">2</str> 
<str name="values">2</str> 
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="names">sample3</str> 
<str name="sno">3</str> 
<str name="values">4</str> 
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

And my response when query string `q=sample1` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
   <int name="status">0</int> 
   <int name="QTime">0</int> 
   <lst name="params">
      <str name="q">*:*</str> 
   </lst>
 </lst>
 <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" /> 
</response>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q`, by itself will search in whatever field defined in `defaultSearchField` (in schema.xml).

If you were to copy all your interesting text into the default field, that search would work. Alternatively, you could pass the field name in your query. `q=names:sample1` should also return results.

Comment: yes, but I gave <defaultSearchField>names</defaultSearchField> in schema.xml. But still its not seaching, when i use q=sample1.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test project based on the default example provided in Solr 6.6.2 with MySql integration (assuming it's kinda related to your integration with postgres). I had this problem which turned out to be simply the naming of the fields.

In the config file for DataImportHandler (in most "Solr tutorial to index database" tutorials, it's called **data-config.xml**), the name of the `<field>` element must also be in the **schema.xml** file. I used the configs from the default examples that ship with Solr, there the field to query is **_text_**.

It's this line in the **data-config.xml** file below:
`<field column="name" name="_text_"/>`

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1" 
        user="root" 
        password=""/>
        <document>
            <entity name="product" pk="id"
                query="select id,name from products"
                deltaImportQuery="SELECT id,name from products WHERE id='${dih.delta.id}'"
                deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM products  WHERE updated_at > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
                >
                <field column="id" name="id"/>
                <field column="name" name="_text_"/> 
            </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**Schema.xml** (must contain the following entry):

`<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

After fixing that, queries such as **/select?q=foo** returned non-empty results.